# Node.js - How to sync files to/from GitHub

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am just beginning to work with Node.js.

I have run `npm init`.

One of the items it prompts me for is a Git repository.   I provided the address to a new (only containing the README.md) public GitHub repository.

If I create a new file from my desktop and check it in to the repository -- how does that file get synced to my server running Node.js.

Is there an npm command to do so or is it handled automatically?

Comment: "how do I sync that to my server running Node.js"  What do you mean by this?

Comment: I still don't understand.  You have a server that reads from Git?  And what does that have to do with NPM?

Comment: Why does npm init ask for a Git repository location if it isn't used anywhere? 

Pardon my ignorance, as I mentioned I am just beginning to work with Node.js.

Comment: `npm init` asks for your repo information so that if you publish your application to NPM, it knows where to get your code and various versions of it.  That's all it's for.

Comment: Oh okay, so basically if it's just if you make your application redistributable for other folks to download?

Answer (score 1):

@Brad's answer above was helpful.

I discovered Notepad++ has built in support for writing directly to an SSH/SFTP location, which allows me to write code from the convenience of my desktop (instead of nano or vi on the server).

Answer (score 0):

Workflow as follows:

```
Create Git (on git hub),

clone to local,

npm init ( the git repo prompt is just for reference (AFAIK), it uses it on npm website)

while(1){

    add some code,

    increment package version

    commit,

    git push,

    npm publish,

    optional un-publish old UNUSED versions

}
```